# Is it possible to reference Bitbucket repository variable inside .env file of Laravel?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to implement bitbucket-pipelines for continuous deployment on AWS. What I'm trying to achieve is to create variables in the .env.example file of Laravel that eventually are pulled from Bitbucket repository variables.

Basically, I want to define the variables inside .env.example something like this:

```
DB_USERNAME="${DB_USERNAME}"
DB_PASSWORD="${DB_PASSWORD}"
```

Then, I also define them inside Bitbucket's Repository Variables using the same key name (eg `DB_USERNAME`), and then when running the bitbucket-pipelines.yml, I am copying the .env.example to .env like this `- cp .env.example .env`

What I am expecting it to do, is basically replace `DB_USERNAME` with the values that I defined inside Bitbucket repository variables, but that doesn't happen. Instead if I look inside my .env file after the deployment, the value of `DB_USERNAME` is `${DB_USERNAME}`

Any idea if this is actually doable? Perhaps I'm not doing it right? Thanks.

Comment: Each environment specifies the variables needed for your application to run. That’s why they’re called _environment_ variables. So in Bitbucket, you would define the variable values needed to run your application within Bitbucket Pipelines, and then AWS would have the environment variable values to run your application on AWS, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Although, I understand the process, but I don't understand why my way of doing it doesn't work. So if you have an advice, please let me know.

Comment: Because you don’t pull environment variables into an **.env** file. **.env** files are for when environment variables aren’t available or easily-updatable, i.e. running locally. Just have your Laravel app read the values from the environment.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I want to achieve. I am trying to automatically deploy my project on AWS using Docker. That means that by the time my image is build, I want to have all those environment variables inside of it, so that the image can be saved as a binary file in ECR. 

So, if ever I need to spin up another identical container, in a matter of seconds, I want to do that without having to manually add .env variables.

Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Daniel Did you ever get anything figured out on this? I am curious..

Comment: @DanielR. as above did you ever make progress here? I think with some more details I may be able to solve your problem.

Comment: What I end up doing, was to create the .env file on the fly using a sh script that I run in the bitbucket-pipelines.yml as it gets acces to bitbucket deployment variables at that point.

Comment: @DanielR. Hey, i have same problem, can you show me your sh script

Comment: @RomanShevchenko, sure... here's an example ```cat >>src/.env <<EOF

DB_DATABASE="${DB_DATABASE}"
DB_USERNAME="${DB_USERNAME}"
DB_PASSWORD="${DB_PASSWORD}"
DB_PORT=3306

EOF```

Comment: @RomanShevchenko added the solution as an answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was to create a build.sh file that will be called in the bitbucket-pipelines.yml like this:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    development:
      - step:
          deployment: development
          script:
            - chmod +x ./build.sh
            - ./build.sh
```

Which will basically pull the environment variables from Bitbucket deployments and add them to the .env at the moment of build, like this:

```
cat >>src/.env <<EOF
  DB_DATABASE="${DB_DATABASE}"
  DB_USERNAME="${DB_USERNAME}"
  DB_PASSWORD="${DB_PASSWORD}"
EOF
```